# wp_editor disable after reaching character count limit

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor

I want to disable input into an instance of wp_editor on the front end. This accurately tracks the number of characters, but allows input after the limit is reached.

```
function my_char_count( $initArray ) {

  if ( ! is_admin() ) {   

    $initArray['setup'] = <<<JS
[function(ed) {
    ed.on('keyup', function(e) {

        var content = ed.getContent().replace(/(<[a-zA-Z\/][^<>]*>|\[([^\]]+)\])|(\s+)/ig,''); 
        var max = 20;
        var len = content.length;

        var diff = max - len; 
        if ( diff < 1 ) {
            // none of these prevents input
            ed.stopPropagation();
            ed.preventDefault();
            tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
            return false;

        }    
        document.getElementById("character_count").innerHTML = "Characters Left: " + diff;    

    });

}][0]
JS;
  }

    return $initArray;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_char_count' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `keyup` event is too late.

If you use the `keypress` event instead of `keyup`, then this seems to work:

```
ed.on( 'keypress', function(e) {
    var content = ed.getContent().replace(
        /(<[a-zA-Z\/][^<>]*>|\[([^\]]+)\])|(\s+)/ig, '' );
    var max = 20;
    var len = content.length;
    var diff = max - len;       

    if ( diff < 1 )
        tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);

    document.getElementById("character_count").innerHTML = "Characters Left: " + diff;
} );
```

The `keypress` event will not log keys like *Alt*, *Enter*, *Control*, *ArrowUp*, ... so when the maximum allowed content length is reached, we won't get stuck!

This should also work for the `keydown`, but it logs all keys, so we would then we have to add exceptions for the allowed keys.