# Add word limit in wordpress posts editor

Tags: custom-post-types

hey guys complete newbie over here and I wand to add an character limit in wordpress default text editor for posts.
P.S I don't want an excerpt limit I want a word limit in posts.
please give step by step instructions as I have no idea about coding
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wp\_editor disable after reaching character count limit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236484/wp-editor-disable-after-reaching-character-count-limit)

Answer (score -1):

You may check [this link about Limit the Number of Words or Characters in WordPress Editor](https://kaspars.net/blog/wordpress/limit-number-words-characters-in-wordpress-editor)